# How can I have multiple animations with different end frames?

Tags: animation

I'm making a simple character for a game in Blender and have 2 animations so far. One is the walk animation which only has 24 frames while the other is an idle animation that has 29 frames. How can I make the walk animation not go beyond the 24th frame? Thanks!

Comment: As you said walk animation has 24 frames so it should not go over 24th frame anyway, imho... Also you didn't say it was about exporting to Unity... !

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Unity automatically cuts the animation depending on the last frame. Why haven't I exported it sooner to check lol.